# Create a user passing in a user object (Microsoft Graph)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to create a user using a microsoft graph call using this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

However, is there a way to create a user by passing in a User object or a json representation of a user object in an azure function as a parameter As shown below?

**[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "user/settings")] HttpRequest req, ILogger logger, User user)**

Also, is there a way to read the whole req.Body (w/ additional properties) and create a user, instead of only applying the required parameters (shown below)? Each and every user will have different properties

```
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "displayName-value",
    MailNickname = "mailNickname-value",
    UserPrincipalName = "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "password-value"
    }
};
await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I don't think we can pass a User object to function directly to create the user. But we can pass all of the properties into the function to create it. As your second question mentioned, it is not easy for us to create the user if every user has different properties. So we can pass all of the properties as json into function and then read the json from the `req` and concat these properties as json string. After that, do not use graph sdk to create user. Do a post request with graph api by ourself like below code:

```
string str = "{\"displayName":\"xxxx\",\"mailNickname\":\"xxxx\"}";

var content = new StringContent(str, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "your token");
var response = client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users", content).Result;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, when you create a user, there are required fields that must be filled out (accountEnabled, displayName, onPremisesImmutableId, password, etc.). If i were to use a user object and pass it in as content in the req, it will not be created cause it does not specify the required field (ex: password = null. Password would need to be set). Is there a workaround to this while passing in the json?